# Librosa "melspectrogram() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" occurs although prior loaded with librosa.load

Tags: python, audio, directory, librosa, spectrogram

I get this error "Melspectrogram() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" in Python for the following code:

```
import librosa
def prepare_audio(audio_path):
  list_matrices = []
  y,sr = librosa.load(audio_path,sr=22050)
  melspect = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y)
  list_matrices.append(melspect)
  return list_matrices

all_X_data = []
targets = []

from pathlib import Path
path = '/Users/xyz/Desktop/Audio_Samplepack'
pathlist = Path(path).glob('**/*.wav')
for path in pathlist:
     path_in_str = str(path)
     audio = prepare_audio(path_in_str)
     all_X_data += audio
     targets += ([0]*len(audio))
```

With this code I want to prepare audio data for a machine learning algorithm. The idea is to browse through a directory of audio, create the spectrogram for each audio file and put the spectrogram values inside a matrix.

On the official librosa page (https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html) it says:
"If a time-series input y, sr is provided, then its magnitude spectrogram S is first computed, and then mapped onto the mel scale by mel_f.dot(S**power)."
So I thought by using these two lines:

```
y,sr = librosa.load(audio_path,sr=22050)
  melspect = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y)
```

I would have prepared y properly before passing it to the melspectrogram function, but I get the above error message - does anyone know why this occurs? (I thought liborsa.load would prepare the data properly to pass it to the melspectrogram function?)

Maybe somebody knows how to fix this issue or can recommend me a way to prepare the spectrogram data in a more efficient way.

EDIT:
So apparently it is possible to load the spectrogram into the matrix with the following code:

```
import librosa
def prepare_audio(audio_path):
  list_matrices = []
  y,sr = librosa.load(audio_path,sr=22050)
  D = np.abs(librosa.stft(y))**2
  S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(S=D, sr=sr)
  list_matrices.append(S)
  return list_matrices
```

Even though I found another way to solve it, it still would be interesting to know what would be the explanation to the original question I guess

Comment: You need to use keyword arguments instead of positional arguments in new version of librosa.